# Combining two lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists. I am trying to combine the two so that the new list `I7` has the `Velprof_list` elements in `I7[0][2]`. The current and expected outputs are included.

```
Velprof_list=[[1.12852034], [0.59581739], [1.69459738], [0.64335001]]
I6=[[(0.5, -0.5), (1.0, 0.0)],
 [(0.5, -0.5), (0.0, -1.0)],
 [(1.5, -0.5), (0.0, -1.0)],
 [(0.5, -1.5), (1.0, 0.0)]]

I7=I6+Velprof_list
print(I7)
```

The current output is

```
[[(0.5, -0.5), (1.0, 0.0)],
 [(0.5, -0.5), (0.0, -1.0)],
 [(1.5, -0.5), (0.0, -1.0)],
 [(0.5, -1.5), (1.0, 0.0)],
 [1.12852034],
 [0.59581739],
 [1.69459738],
 [0.64335001]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[(0.5, -0.5), (1.0, 0.0),1.12852034],
 [(0.5, -0.5), (0.0, -1.0),0.59581739],
 [(1.5, -0.5), (0.0, -1.0),1.69459738],
 [(0.5, -1.5), (1.0, 0.0),0.64335001]]
```

Comment: `[x+y for x,y in zip(I6, Velprof_list)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to align the elements of the first and second lists side by side and then concatenate them using `+`:

```
>>> [ L + x for L, x in zip(I6, Velprof_list) ]
[[(0.5, -0.5), (1.0, 0.0), 1.12852034],
 [(0.5, -0.5), (0.0, -1.0), 0.59581739],
 [(1.5, -0.5), (0.0, -1.0), 1.69459738],
 [(0.5, -1.5), (1.0, 0.0), 0.64335001]]
```